# error in DeserializeObject while deserialize dictionary in c#

Tags: c#, json

This is my class:

```
public class GetQuestionResponse
{
    public Dictionary<uint, string> Answers { get; set; } 
    public uint Status { get; set; }
    public string Question { get; set; }
}
```

this is the string I try to deserialize

```
"{\"Answers\":[[0,\"Melissa Mao\"],[1,\"Ren Mikihara\"],[2,\"Teletha \\\"Tessa\\\" Testarossa\"],[3,\"Kyoko Tokiwa\"]],\"Question\":\"In the anime, Full Metal Panic!, who is Kaname's best friend?\",\"Status\":1}"
```

And this is the lone of code I using:

```
GetQuestionResponse response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GetQuestionResponse>(messageStr);
```

The program fail while this line is in run and I don't understand what ....
the error:

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: 'Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type `System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary'2[System.UInt32,System.String]` because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. `{"name":"value"}`) to deserialize correctly.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you need to use your class you should fix your json. it should be

```
 "{ \"Answers\" : {  0:\"Melissa Mao\", 1:\"Ren Mikihara\", 2:\"Teletha \\\"Tessa\\\" Testarossa\", 3:\"Kyoko Tokiwa\" },\"Question\":\"In the anime, Full Metal Panic!, who is Kaname's best friend?\",\"Status\":1}";
```

to Deserialize your json string you need this class

```
public class GetQuestionResponse
    {
        public List<List<object>> Answers { get; set; }
        public string Question { get; set; }
        public int Status { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The string format is incorrect, try yourself:

```
Dictionary<uint, string> answ = new Dictionary<uint, string>();
answ.Add(0, "Melissa Mao");
answ.Add(1, "Ren Mikihara");
answ.Add(2, "Teletha \"Tessa\" Testarossa");
answ.Add(3, "Kyoko Tokiwa");

GetQuestionResponse test = new GetQuestionResponse() { Status = 1, Question= "In the anime, Full Metal Panic!, who is Kaname's best friend?", Answers = answ };

var serialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(test);

GetQuestionResponse deserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GetQuestionResponse>(serialized);
```